# Multiple UIPickerView with same data in one view. How can I get the content of both picker?

Tags: iphone, uipickerview

I have 2 UIPickerviews with the same data. 
At the moment sb is clicking the save-Button I want to get the data from both PickerViews.
I already set a tag to both pickers and I also implemented the function:

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component 
{    
    return [symbolList objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

But I have no idea how to get on both datas at the same time.

Comment: How you are creating your UIPickerViews? Are there private variables or outlets to point those?

Answer (score 1):

For each picker view, use `selectedRowInComponent:` to find out the current selection. Use this to obtain the value from each picker view's data source, e.g:

```
NSString *pickerViewOneSelection = [symbolList objectAtIndex:[pickerViewOne selectedRowInComponent:0]];
NSString *pickerViewTwoSelection = [symbolList objectAtIndex:[pickerViewTwo selectedRowInComponent:0]];
```

I'm assuming that `pickerViewOne` and `pickerViewTwo` are pointers to your two picker views and you've already worked that part out. I have also assumed that your picker has only one component.

Comment: Glad to help! If this is the correct answer for you, please accept it (click the checkmark) so that future visitors know that this was the answer to the question. If you need anything else, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Set tag of pickerview.
first create IBOutlet of both picker view.

and set tag of picker view.
pickerview.tag == 10;

Comment: - (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component 
{    if(pickerview.tag==10){
    return [symbolList objectAtIndex:row];
     }

}